# Is there a RAW legal way to get 3 attacks on second profession?

Tags: optimization, wfrp-2e

As in the title: **I'm looking for a basic profession + advanced profession combination that will result in 3 attacks total**. So far I failed to find such combination.

Context: we will be playing one-shot, starting on second profession +1 upgrade of choice. We are allowed to use 3rd Party books (like Defenders of the Forest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long research (damn, those professions are NOT organized by stats) I found one, just ONE setup:

- **Warleader** as second profession,
- **Bondsmen, Marauder or Reaver** as basic profession.

But if anyone knows other setups that achieve the same thing, I'd love to learn about those.

All of mentioned professions are in a **Career Compendium**, but they are originally from **Tome of Corruption** (Chaos rules expansion essentially, although Norscans aren't technically Chaos slaves).

Comment: I admit I know next to nothing about Warhammer, but wouldn't it be useful to explain **how** these professions interact to give you three attacks? Also, information about **what book** they are from would surely help future readers.

Comment: There is no "interaction" per se. You just choose profession A and you get a legal "exit professions" to choose from. Problem was finding a basic profession (out of bajilion) with +1 attack in advance scheme that also has an exit profession with +2 attack in advance scheme. Sadly, this is how WFRP works, not much choices on player's side going on.

Comment: http://bindslet.dk/rpg/whfrpcareers.html  Is a very useful tool for finding which career paths can lead you where.

Comment: @From This table has the same issue as every other source. It doesn't mark/differentiate advanced careers that are available as 2nd career from those only available as 3rd or 4th career. Which means one still has check entry/exit for every single class to learn how soon it can be reached.

Comment: @NecXelos For this question, I'd first click "Show/hide Career Table", then find all careers with a 2 in the Attacks column (copy to Notepad?). Then I'd click "Show/hide Detailed Careers", and click, for instance, "Warleader". Then I'd see only three basic careers turn red (signifying career entry), which are those three you listed.